# Outputting new datasets or overwriting original list datasets after using lapply on it

Tags: r, lapply

I have about 25 datasets called (AE,CC,CE,CM,DS,EC,DS,LB,MH...)  that I want to add a column to from a reference dataset, DM.

I first made a list of all those data sets

```
all_data = list(AE,CC,CE,CM,DS,EC,DS,LB,MH...)
```

I then applied a dplyr function with lapply to pull the colum i want into all of the datasets in my list

```
new_list =   lapply(all_data, left_join, DM, by="SUBJID")
```

This worked fine, I can see the colum added in the console, but there two things i am wondering. Can I overwrite my original datasets in that list so they are in my global environment? Currently it seems I have to  do something like

```
new_list[4]
```

to access these datasets with the added column, because technically they are locked in a list now. Is it also possible to out put new datasets that are individual and not in a list?

Comment: have a look at `?list2env`

Comment: It looks like it should work but im getting this error.....

Comment: list2env(new_list, envir = globalenv())
Error in list2env(new_list, envir = globalenv()) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Comment: `list2env(new_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)`